# CursorLoader with Fragment inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursorloader

I'm experiencing a really weird behavior and I suppose I'm missing something.

I have an activity that has a Fragment inside. This Fragment has a ViewPager which obviously hosts other Fragments.

To populate that ViewPager I need info from four tables. Once the first loader finishes loading (let's call it 0), I init the other loaders.

The user swipes through the pages and when he/she reaches the last page, the Fragment that is loaded on that last page inits loader 0 again, which takes a huge amount of time to reach onLoaderFinished. If I load that "last page fragment" without being inside the ViewPager, it loads instantly, as expected.

Is there a way to deal with this situation of a Fragment inside a ViewPager using the same Loader that was used to populate the ViewPager itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe a bit of code, please :) and also, try adding more logging into all the loaders so that you see when thery start and when they finish and if they dont start too many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling setOffscreenPageLimit() in onCreate() (after initializing ViewPager). The OffscreenPageLimit sets the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page. With this all of your fragments will instantiate. Though you must not do so if there are large number of pages.

Comment: The offscreen limit is set to 1 by default and that's the value I'm using. With the kind of fragments I have, if I use more than that I can easily get OOM.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by not calling the Loader inside the Fragment and passing the array of data I wanted from the database in a Bundle as a Serializable.